# Why Val and Var behave same for arrays in koltin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
fun Sample(){ 
val x = 10
x = 11 // will give error as it cannot be reassigned

val arr = arrayOf(1,2,3)
arr[0] = 5 // will not give any error but why ? aren't they supposed to be final?
}
```

> Why val doesn't works for arrays?

Comment: `val` says, you cannot change the reference (pointer) it is assigned to in the memory. But the object itself (the array) is mutable, so if you change the value in memory it does not violate the promise of val as you did not changed the memory address arr is assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr` itself is immutable and can't be reassigned....the contents of array are not.  For example you could not do:

```
val arr1 = arrayOf(1,2,3)
val arr2 = arrayOf(4,5,6)


arr1 = arr2 // error
```

An alternative if you want a "read-only" list is to use `listOf()`

Answer (score 1):

By declaring and array as with val, you basically declare the reassigning for the array isn't possible, but array items are still reassignable

Answer (score 0):

`val`s aren't really *immutable data*, it's better to think of them as *read-only references*. You can change the value of a `var`, but you can't change the thing a `val` points at. But that doesn't mean the thing itself can't change!

If the object itself is mutable, or has mutable `var` properties, or has `val` properties that point to other mutable things... you get the idea. You can't guarantee absolute immutable state, it's just not baked into the language (or Java itself - `final` just means you can't reassign the variable!)

---

That's why Kotlin has a bunch of features to try and help you avoid mutable state, or at least to prevent you from changing things. `Collection`s (and the return types of the functions that operate on them) are usually immutable by default, and you have to explicitly ask for a `mutableList` or whatever. That's enforcing immutability by stopping you from accessing methods like `add` and `remove`, but it still doesn't stop you from putting mutable objects in there!

`data class`es are another tool, and that's sort of aimed at a more functional, data-driven approach. The idea is that ideally, you'll just put `val`s in them, and any non-primitive data types you use will also comprise of `val`s - so when you drill down, everything ends in immutable variables, so the whole thing is immutable overall. Things like the `copy` method allow you to "change" the data without actually mutating it, similar to a Copy On Write approach.

---

I'd also say that in my experience, it's not uncommon for arrays specifically to always be treated as a mutable type, though. Like there's no immutable version of an array in Kotlin, and things like F# (which encourages functional transformations on its types) explicitly has setters on its `Array` types. So if you need a read-only array... use a `List`!